# Hash function to iterate through a matrix

Tags: objective-c, c, algorithm, hash, matrix

Given a `NxN` matrix and a `(row,column)` position, what is a method to select a different position in a random (or pseudo-random) order, trying to avoid collisions as much as possible?

For example: consider a `5x5` matrix and start from `(1,2)`

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 X 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

I'm looking for a method like

```
(x,y) hash (x,y);
```

to jump to a different position in the matrix, avoiding collisions as much as possible
(do not care how to return two different values, it doesn't matter, just think of an array).

Of course, I can simply use

```
row = rand()%N;
column = rand()%N;
```

but it's not that good to avoid collisions.
I thought I could apply twice a simple hash method for both `row` and `column` and use the results as new coordinates, but I'm not sure this is a good solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your goal? Is it to iterate the matrix in a random order?

Comment: Yes, avoiding collisions as much as possible

Answer (score 3):

Can you determine the order of the walk before you start iterating? If your matrices are large, this approach isn't space-efficient, but it is straightforward and collision-free.  I would do something like:

1. Generate an array of all of the coordinates.  Remove the starting position from the list.
2. Shuffle the list (there's sample code for a Fisher-Yates shuffle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray))
3. Use the shuffled list for your walk order.

Comment: The wikipedia page for the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shows a way to initialize and shuffle simultaneously, which can be used here

Answer (score 2):

*Edit 2 & 3:*  A modular approach: Given s array elements, choose a [prime p of form 2+3*n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57162/number-of-kp-bmod-q-classes-when-q-p-1), p>s. For i=1 to p, use cells (i*i*i)%p when that value is in range 1...s-1. (For row-length r, cell #c subscripts are c%r, c/r.)

Effectively, this method uses H(i) = (i*i*i) mod p as a hash function.  The [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57162/number-of-kp-bmod-q-classes-when-q-p-1) shows that as i ranges from 1 to p, H(i) takes on each of the values from 0 to p-1, exactly one time each.

For example, with s=25 and p=29 or 47, this uses cells in following order:

```
p=29: 1 8 6 9 13 24 19 4 14 17 22 18 11 7 12 3 15 10 5 16 20 23 2 21 0
p=47: 1 8 17 14 24 13 15 18 7 4 10 2 6 21 3 22 9 12 11 23 5 19 16 20 0
```

according to bc code like

```
s=25;p=29;for(i=1;i<=p;++i){t=(i^3)%p; if(t<s){print " ",t}}
```

The text above shows the suggestion I made in *Edit 2* of my answer.  The text below shows my first answer.

*Edit 0: (This is the suggestion to which Seamus's comment applied):* A simple method to go through a vector in a "random appearing" way is to repeatedly add d (d>1) to an index. This will access all elements if d and s are coprime (where s=vector length). Note, my example below is in terms of a vector; you could do the same thing independently on the other axis of your matrix, with a different delta for it, except a problem mentioned below would occur.  Note, "coprime" means that gcd(d,s)=1. If s is variable, you'd need [gcd() code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm).
*Example:* Say s is 10. gcd(s,x) is 1 for x in {1,3,7,9} and is not 1 for x in {2,4,5,6,8,10}. Suppose we choose d=7, and start with i=0. i will take on values 0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, which modulo 10 is 0, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 6, 3, 0.
*Edit 1 & 3:* Unfortunately this will have a problem in the two-axis case; for example, if you use d=7 for x axis, and e=3 for y-axis, while the first 21 hits will be distinct, it will then continue repeating the same 21 hits.  To address this, treat the whole matrix as a vector, use d with gcd(d,s)=1, and convert cell numbers to subscripts as above.

Comment: +1 for a useful addition here, but it's worth noting that the output is not especially random looking. You're basically identifing a particular move and repeating it, wrapping around the edges as needed.  In this case, it's three down and three to the left, which I think will be pretty identifiable as a pattern after just a couple iterations.

Comment: With wraparound, I think it would take at least three or four iterations to be obvious. :)  Anyway, I've added Edit 2 with a modular method that presents a far less obvious pattern, except for the first two or three cells used.

Comment: Nice solution. What is `n` in the modular approach you provided? Besides, if `s` is big, it may be not that easy to find a prime with such a form, and it seems to be the only parameter that changes the sequence...

Comment: `n` is any odd number large enough that `2+3*n >= s`.  I have posted a separate answer below that shows a half-dozen lines of code for finding such a prime.  For any array you can display on screen it will take less than 10 microseconds on most PC's.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to iterate through the matrix, what is wrong with row++; if (row == N) {row = 0; column++}?

If you iterate through the row and the column independently, and each cycles back to the beginning after N steps, then the (row, column) pair will interate through only N of the N^2 cells of the matrix.

If you want to iterate through all of the cells of the matrix in pseudo-random order, you could look at questions here on random permutations.

Comment: I don't want to simply iterate through a matrix, I need to jump to different positions randomly. I'm sorry, my question seems not to be clear. I've edited it adding an example.

Comment: In that case, since you can translate between a (row, column) pair and a number between 1..N^2, you are asking for a random permutation of the numbers 1..N^2, as described in more detail by Seamus Campbell.

Answer (score 1):

This is a companion answer to address a question about my previous answer:  How to find an appropriate prime `p >= s` (where `s` = the number of matrix elements) to use in the hash function `H(i) = (i*i*i) mod p`.

We need to find a prime of form `3n+2`, where `n` is any odd integer such that 3*n+2 >= s.  Note that `n` odd gives `3n+2 = 3(2k+1)+2 = 6k+5` where k need not be odd.  In the example code below, `p = 5+6*(s/6);` initializes `p` to be a number of form `6k+5`, and `p += 6;` maintains `p` in this form.

The code below shows that half-a-dozen lines of code are enough for the calculation.  Timings are shown after the code, which is reasonably fast: 12 us at s=half a million, 200 us at s=half a billion, where us denotes microseconds.

```
// timing how long to find primes of form 2+3*n by division
// jiw 20 Sep 2011
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
double ttime(double base) {
  struct timeval tod;
  gettimeofday(&tod, NULL);
  return tod.tv_sec + tod.tv_usec/1e6 - base;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int d, s, p, par=0;
  double t0=ttime(0);
  ++par; s=5000;  if (argc > par) s = atoi(argv[par]);
  p = 5+6*(s/6);
  while (1) {
    for (d=3; d*d<p; d+=2)
      if (p%d==0) break;
    if (d*d >= p) break;
    p += 6;
  }
  printf ("p = %d after %.6f seconds\n", p, ttime(t0));
  return 0;
}
```

Timing results on 2.5GHz Athlon 5200+:

```
qili ~/px > for i in 0 00 000 0000 00000 000000; do ./divide-timing 500$i; done
p = 5003 after 0.000008 seconds
p = 50021 after 0.000010 seconds
p = 500009 after 0.000012 seconds
p = 5000081 after 0.000031 seconds
p = 50000021 after 0.000072 seconds
p = 500000003 after 0.000200 seconds

qili ~/px > factor 5003 50021 500009 5000081 50000021 500000003
5003: 5003
50021: 50021
500009: 500009
5000081: 5000081
50000021: 50000021
500000003: 500000003
```

*Update 1* Of course, timing is not determinate (ie, can vary substantially depending on the value of `s`, other processes on machine, etc); for example:

```
qili ~/px > time for i in 000 004 010 058 070 094 100 118 184; do ./divide-timing 500000$i; done
p = 500000003 after 0.000201 seconds
p = 500000009 after 0.000201 seconds
p = 500000057 after 0.000235 seconds
p = 500000069 after 0.000394 seconds
p = 500000093 after 0.000200 seconds
p = 500000099 after 0.000201 seconds
p = 500000117 after 0.000201 seconds
p = 500000183 after 0.000211 seconds
p = 500000201 after 0.000223 seconds
real 0m0.011s
user 0m0.002s
sys  0m0.004s
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a double hash function to get a better distribution inside the matrix,
but given that you cannot avoid colisions, what I suggest is to use an array of sentinels
and mark the positions you visit, this way you are sure you get to visit a cell once.