# App crashes after sometime : - (void)viewDidUnload method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my iPad App,

I am using AQGridView.

This app is all about matching the cards to its categories.

In that I am deleting the cells.

If I am just opening the app for a few minutes **it will not crashed**.

But If I am playing the app for **3 to 4 minutes** and **deleting many cells** it is getting crashes in the method.

Some **memory leaks** that I could not solve...

I have one array called `imageMarray`

I am doing shuffling on it.

**In View Did Load.**

```
 imageMArray=[NSMutableArray initWithArray:CategoryImages];
 imageMArray=[[self shuffleOnlyArray:imageMArray] retain];
```

In shuffleOnlyArray Method

```
-(NSMutableArray*)shuffleOnlyArray:(NSMutableArray*)sourceArray
{
    NSMutableArray *destArray1 = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: [sourceArray count]] autorelease];

    srandom( time(NULL));

    while ([sourceArray count] != 0)
    {
        NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)(random() % [sourceArray count]);
        id item = [sourceArray objectAtIndex: index];
        [destArray1 addObject: item];
        [sourceArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }

    [sourceArray release];
    sourceArray=nil;
    return destArray1;
}
```

**And In shuffle Method I am writing**

```
imageMArray=[[self shuffleOnlyArray:imageMArray] retain];
```

**Where should I write release.
So it does remove memory leak.**

Comment: Have you tried deleting the line?

Comment: Previously It was crashing on another view controller in a viewDidUnload method, So I have commented the every line of that method..Now it is crashing in another view controller.

Comment: Why even set this stuff to nil?  Under ARC, it's unnecessary, and without ARC, a simple release message will suffice.

Comment: OK will check and removing nil...wait for the comment further....

Comment: Still, App crashes but this time it is not shown in which method it is getting crashed.

Comment: Post some code so that we can help you more.

Comment: I have updated answer in the other [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733394/nsmutablearray-memory-management-while-calling-methods/9733501#9733501)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think the issue is with reference counting, select 'Product > Analyze' to get Xcode to check all of your retain and releases and other issues.

Comment: You are right I have done that and my issue has been solved.