# Shuffle the content in a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray)

I have some values in a `NSMutableArray`. Now i need to shuffle these values. Can someone tell me how to shuffle these values.

Sorry i don't have any code to demonstrate.

I went through this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray) post, which suggest to use `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:`, but can someone show me how it is done. An example or a tutorial which explains this would help.

Comment: Why didn't you look at the other answers for that question?? [One of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/56656/689356) provides a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
for (int i = [array count] - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    int j = arc4random() % (i+1);
    [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
}
```

array is Your `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: For a good shuffle, you don't want to mod with `array count` but with `i`. See [the Fisher-Yates shuffle‌​](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm).