# shuffled value on uibutton text from array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

In my application I'm having 4 buttons. On each click I want to show the `UIButton` title shuffled value from array. 
I tried this one [What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray) 
But its not working.

Comment: Can you post your code what you have tried, then you might get helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someplace you make an array :

In your header (.h) file

```
NSArray *words;
```

and a little below that

```
- (IBAction)aButtonWasClicked:(id)sender;
```

In you code file (.m), like viewDidLoad

```
words = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", nil] retain];
```

(in ios 6 you might do it like this

```
words = @[@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four"];
```

Then you do this :

```
- (IBAction)aButtonWasClicked:(id)sender {
    int value = arv4random() % ([words count] -1);
    UIButton *mybutton = (UIButton *)sender;
    [mybbutton setTitle:[words objectAtIndex:value] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Just remember to hook all 4 buttons to the same Action.

Thats all there is to it. You can easily add a function to make sure no button has the same title and so on.

Comment: its says No known instance method SetCaption.Please help me

Comment: My bad. I have updated the answer. This happens when you write code from memory only :) It is setTitle with forState. Answer updated

Answer (score 1):

You will get your index of array shuffled and then use that index to pick value.

```
 int rndIndex = arc4random()%[yourArray count];

 [yourArray objectAtIndex:rndIndex];
```