# Is there a way to set restrictions on arc4random()'s results?

Tags: objective-c, random, arc4random

I'm making three random choices between two classes, A and B. I need to avoid getting B all three times.

Is there a way to stop `arc4random()` from giving me that result?

Comment: So if you get two nodes of type b, then you should manually make the third node of type a, by bypassing the RNG in that case.

Comment: `arc4random` isn't the issue. It doesn't display anything. It just gives a number. You simply need to adjust your logic so you always have at least one "a" node.

Comment: [How to get not twice the same array value in a row?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13745248)

Answer (score 3):

- One approach is: If your random routine gives you an unacceptable answer, run it again until it gives you an acceptable answer.

  For example, in a solitaire game app of mine, I shuffle a deck and deal some of it into a layout which must be solvable. But what if it isn't solvable? I repeat that: I shuffle the deck *again* and deal it *again*. I keep doing that until the layout I've dealt *is* solvable. All of that happens before the user sees anything, so the user doesn't know what I've been up to behind the scenes to guarantee that the layout makes sense.
- In your case, where the possibilities are so limited, another obvious alternative would be this: use a simple combinatorial algorithm to generate beforehand all *acceptable* combinations of three nodes. Now use `arc4random` to pick one of those combinations. So, for example:

  ```
  var list = [[String]]()
  let possibilities = ["A","B"]
  for x in possibilities {
      for y in possibilities {
          for z in possibilities {
              list.append([x,y,z])
          }
      }
  }
  list.removeLast()
  ```

  Now `list` is an array of all possible triples of "A" or "B", but without ["B","B","B"]. So now pick an element at random and for each of its letters, if it is "A", use class A, and if it is "B", use class B. (Of course I suppose we could have done this with actual classes or instances, but it seems simplest to encode it as letters.)

Answer (score 0):

BOOLs and loops to the rescue...

```
BOOL classA = false;
BOOL classB = false;

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {

    int r = arc4random() % 2;

    if(i < 2) {
        if(r == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Class A");
            classA = true;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Class B");
            classB = true;
        }
    } else {
        if(classA == false)
            NSLog(@"Class A");
        if(classB == false)
            NSLog(@"Class B");
    }
}
```

The 2 BOOLs guarantee that each class has at least one member for each 3 cycle run.

Comment: FYI - Use `YES` and `NO` with `BOOL`, not `true` and `false`.

Comment: @rmaddy - What's the difference in the context above? I've been using true/false for some time without issues.

Comment: This is a bit pedantic and In the end they probably all mean the same thing but `BOOL` is specific to Objective-C and is meant to only ever have two values: `NO` and `YES`. `true` and `false` are meant to be used with different types.

Comment: One other thing. Never use `==` with `BOOL`. Just do `if (someBool)` or `if (!someBool)` to test for `YES` and `NO` respectively.