# How to display (5 or 7 or 8 etc) images from 25 images randomly without repetition from array in iphone

Tags: iphone

In my `FirstViewcontroller` I have picker containing `1` to `25` values, if the user select 5 in the picker on the next screen it should display 5 images randomly out of 25 images without repetition of that 5 images. If user selects another number means it takes that number as input and it should display images according to that number. If I run my code means every time it showing all 25 images not selected number images. Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
    myImageNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [myImageNames addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"]];
    [myImageNames addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue.png"]];
    [myImageNames addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LightRed.png"]];
    [myImageNames addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange.png"]];
    .
    .
    .

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self  selector:@selector(ChangingImgView:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) ChangingImgView:(int)selectedNumberFromPicker {
    selectedNumberFromPicker = [num intValue];

    for (int i=0; i < selectedNumberFromPicker; i++) {

        index = arc4random() % 25;
        NSString *strIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",index];
        [myImageNames addObject:strIndex];
        imgBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        imgBtn.frame = CGRectMake(250, 300, 170, 220);
        UIImage *img = [myImageNames objectAtIndex:index];
        [imgBtn setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [imgBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickingOnImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:imgBtn];
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: just make array of all images and then remove object one by one ...you will get your result..:)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use NSSet instead of using NSMutableArray

doc apple

`You can use sets as an alternative to arrays when the order of elements isn’t important and performance in testing whether an object is contained in the set is a consideration—while arrays are ordered, testing for membership is slower than with sets.`

Comment: Thanks for giving reply, could you please explain me with brief about this

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `suffle` your `myImageNames` which has `images` using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56656/1106035) link.

Now `display` first 5 `images` from `myImageNames`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 5;
NSMutableArray *inputImages = [myImageNames mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *randomImages;

for (int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
    int index = arc4random_uniform([inputImages count]);
    [randomImages addObject:[inputImages objectAtIndex:index]];
    [inputImages removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for loop to get the particular number of images for random indexes.  Use selectedImgArray to display the selected images. myImageNames is your original array.

```
NSInteger index;
NSMutableArray *selectedImgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i < selectedNumberFromPicker; i++) {
    index = arc4random() % 25;
    UIImage *selImg = (UIImage *)[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index];
    if ([selectedImgArray containsObject:selImg]) {
        i--;
        continue;
    }
    [selectedImgArray addObject:selImg];

}
```