# generating random numbers without consecutive repetition

Tags: objective-c, random

How can I generate random integers from 0 - 4 in such a way that the same number is not generated twice consecutively? For example, if 3 is the number that is generated the first time then 0,1,2,4 will be the possible numbers for random generation the second time. If 2 is generated the second time then 0,1,3,4 will be the possible numbers for random generation the third time and so on.

Comment: You can't make random less random.  Use an NSSet for uniquing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate random number from given number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680582/generate-random-number-from-given-number)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/56656/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR - Those aren't dupes of his question.  He is not asking for a shuffle.

Comment: @HotLicks: You are right. I overlooked the word *consecutive* when reading the question. Sorry!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int oldrand = <prior random number>;
int adder = randomNumberGenerator() % 4;
int newrand = (oldrand + adder + 1) % 5;
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand how this solution works. I would appreciate it if you explain further.

Comment: @oopology - You have a number 0 .. 4.  You want another number in the same range, only not exactly the same number.  So add any number between 1 and 4 to the first number, then, if the addition overflows, "wrap it around".  So if your first number is 3 and you pick a random value 2, then add 3 + 2 + 1, you get 6, which is larger than your range.  But 5 wraps to 0 and 6 wraps to 1, so your result is 1.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I wish I had enough up votes to give your explanation and answer an up vote.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint32_t myRandomNumber(uint32_t upperBound, uint32_t avoid) {
    if (avoid < upperBound) {
        --upperBound;
    }
    uint32_t number = arc4random_uniform(upperBound);
    if (number >= avoid) {
        ++number;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Call it like this the first time:

```
uint32_t number = myRandomNumber(5, 5);
```

Call it like this after the first time:

```
number = myRandomNumber(5, number);
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be generated with using 2 arrays; 1 is sorted and the other is created by taking random objects form sorted like

```
-(NSMutableArray *)generateRandomNumbersFrom:(int) a to:(int)b
{

    NSMutableArray * numbersWillBeChosen=[NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray * randomList=[NSMutableArray new];
    //add the numbers that will create your ramdom list in order
    for(int k=0;k<=(b-a);k++)
    {
        [numbersWillBeChosen addObject:@(a+k)];
    }


    //create random list
    for (int p=(b-a)+1; p>0; p--) {

        int rand= arc4random()%p;

        [randomList addObject:[numbersWillBeChosen objectAtIndex:rand]];

        [numbersWillBeChosen removeObjectAtIndex:rand];


    }

    NSLog(@"%@",randomList);

return randomList;
    }
```

and you can call for your situation

```
randList=[self generateRandomNumbersFrom:0 to:4];
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried Hot Lick's answer and it ended up generating duplicates for me (or out of range numbers). But it inspired me to come up with a solution that worked for me.

My code is C#, but you can modify it to suit your needs.

```
//Returns a random number not same as previous random number. ie. no 2 consec random
public static int NonConsecRandom(int max, int? lastNum=null)
{
    if (lastNum == null)
        return Random.Range(0, max);

    int last = (int)lastNum;            
    return Random.Range(last + 1, last + max) % max;
}
```

**Explanation:**

first block just returns a random number if there was no previously generated number.

the second part generates a random number from the "other numbers".

For example if my "max" was 5, the possible random numbers are:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Lets say my last number was 2, now I want a random number among [3, 4, 0, 1]

So I generate a random between last+1 and last+max.
i.e. between 3 (inclusive) and 7 (not inclusive)

[3, 4, 5, 6]

Mod any of those numbers with max (i.e. 5) and you'll get a random number in the desired range: [3 , 4, 0, 1]