# fill array with random numbers different from each others?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to have an array with 12 numbers -> 0 to 11
the array must be random, and i don't want to have twice the same number

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a shuffling problem.

Just declare an array like follows

```
NSMutableArray * numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    [numbers addObject:@i];
}
```

Then you can shuffle that array using the [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm

```
for (NSUInteger i = numbers.count - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    NSUInteger n = arc4random_uniform(i+1);
    [numbers exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
```

Comment: I didn’t downvote you, but I think your FY algorithm has something wrong, the way you calculate `n` is a little bit strange, and will probably cause index out of bounds problem. I think you don’t need the final `+ i`.

Comment: I stand corrected, I changed it with a more reasonable implementation. This is a good comment, as opposed to a useless downvote with no explanation. Thank you

Comment: And incorrect again (oops): the count down has to be until `i > 0`, since otherwise the final exchange will be between index 0 and index 0, which is not very wise. Then the `arc4random_uniform` has to use `i` as upper limit (inclusive, so `i + 1` in the code).

Comment: My mistake, I stand corrected again. Thank you for the comments, I don't know when my head is today :)

Comment: Just follow the link you provided, where it clearly says `j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i` (`j` is `n` in your code). If you use the length as upper limit, elements at the start of the array has higher probability of ending at the end.

Comment: @ChHnsn you're welcome. By the way I've seen your suggested edit. `@i` is modern Objective-C syntax and you should prefer it to the wordy alternative `[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create an array and fill it in a loop with the numbers 0 to 11. In a second step, you shuffle that array: [What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray)

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

        int randomNumber = min + rand() % (max-min);
        [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomNumber]];  

    }
```

Not sure if the syntax is correct, im on a Windows machine now

Comment: Well, that will fill and array of 12 elements… all of them being the `NSNumber` 15. Not sure if that’s what the OP was looking for :P

Comment: What's `min`? What's `max`? And regardless of that, this will produce an array with 12 elements all equals to `15`. Also how does this guarantees uniqueness of the elements?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Min and max are whatever you want them to be. It's pretty self-explanatory. Sorry about the typo, I fixed it now

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Where exactly does he state that he wants every number unique? As far as I know, he just wants a list of random numbers, not necessarily unique.

Comment: The OP said “i don't want to have twice the same number”.

Comment: Oh! I must be blind! By the way, what's OP?