# Present pair of users at random, and not show that same pair again

Tags: ios, combinations

I am trying to figure out how to present a pair of users from an array of users to the `current_user` of the app, and not have the `current_user` see that same pair of users again.  Mathematically, I understand that this is a `n choose 2`, where n is the size of the user array.  However, I am unsure how to set up the data structure so it could, *at random*, present all of the combination of pairs to the `current_user`.  Thanks!

Comment: 1/ Generate all pairs, random shuffle, and output.
2/ If you only need to generate a few combinations from a large <n>, keep a white list of generated pair and loop the random generation until a new pair didn't exist in the white list. It can loop to die if <n> is small or you need to output most of the possible pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a class that consisted of the id's for two users.

```
@interface userPair: NSObject

 @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger user1id;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger user2id;

@end
```

I would just create a NSMutableArray of all possible pairs then run this awesome shuffle method: (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56656/793607))

```
- (void)shuffle
{
    NSUInteger count = [self count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
        NSInteger nElements = count - i;
        NSInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
        [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
}
```