# Generate random index which is not generated again

Tags: objective-c, arrays, random

I have an array of **names** and an array of **numbers**.

My Person class has a property for both the **name** and the **number**. I want to assign the random values to random people.

Suppose I have an array with the **strings** `@"mary" , @"Jack" and @"ABhraham"`
and another array with the **numbers** `122, 378, 987`, I want to assign them these values randomly. I used the `arc4random()` method but it sometimes returns the same value again.

Comment: @Reformer No, that's not the one the methi1999 is looking for (although the title suggests that he is). He's actually looking for FY-shuffle.

Comment: Are your arrays sized in 10s, 100s, 1000s?  Then you can use a more brutish method, like a loop, trying to assign unless it was already assigned.  The benefit is you don't have to read up on FY and you can get on with your project.  The downside is you miss learning something cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Use dictionaries, set keys for each person.

**OR**

2: Use mutable arrays for both, removing each object as you assign it.

```
while(arrayOfNumberTags.count>0){
    float randomIndex = arc4random() % arrayOfNumberTags.count;
    int tagForPerson = [arrayOfNumberTags objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    //Create the Person object with the tag and any person
    [arrayOfNumberTags removeObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [*Fisher–Yates shuffle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Create an array that has numbers zero through `N-1`, inclusive, where `N` is the number of elements in your arrays; this will be the array of indexes. Then apply Fisher-Yates shuffle to the array of indexes. Now you can use `number[index[i]]` for each `name[i]`.

Here is a [link to an answer that provides a Fisher-Yates Shuffle implementation in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56656/335858).