# iOS loops and leaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, memory-leaks

I have a loop where I'd like to redefine the contents of an array with every iteration.  I'm worried about leaks.  Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
for (int i=0;i<numberOfReps;i++){
  NSArray *shuffledArray=[self shuffleArray:originalArray];
  // use shuffled array
}
```

Thanks for reading!

EDIT:

Here is shuffleArray (credit to Kristopher Johnson from [What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray/56656#56656)):

```
-(NSArray*)shuffleArray:(NSArray*)array{
    NSMutableArray *newArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
    NSUInteger count = [newArray count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
        int nElements = count - i;
        int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
        [newArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:newArray];
}
```

(And I am using ARC.)

Comment: You need to post the contents of the -shuffleArray method. There's no leak in the code that you have posted thus far.

Comment: You can easily test this by creating your own class and putting an NSLog statement in the `init` and `dealloc` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we're using ARC and the `shuffleArray` method is fine, this bit of code will be fine too.  There's no leak in the code you've posted.

Each `shuffledArray` is deallocated at the end of each iteration of the loop (unless you're saving it somewhere else).  And there is only one `originalArray`.

---

EDIT: After the edit, again, assuming we're using ARC, there's no leak with the code.  `newArray` is released as soon as `shuffleArray` returns.  `shuffledArray` is released at the end of the loop iteration.  `originalArray` has reference outside the `for` loop, and remains in memory until it has no more references.

The only possible leak here would be whatever you do with `shuffledArray` in the `//use shuffled array` section of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

That depends.

Only if you're sure that the method `shuffleArray` returns an **autoreleased** object then there's no harm with your code, (and this assuming you're not using ARC).

EDIT:
After seeing your code update, regardless if you're using ARC, there's no leak