# How to check is a value already exist in NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm generating random number and adding it to array. But I don't want duplicates to be there. How do I check if the value already exists in array? Thank you!

```
int lowerBound = 0;
int long upperBound = numberOfQuestions;
int randomQuestionNumber = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);
[_randomQuestionNumberArray addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:randomQuestionNumber]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect use case for an `NSMutableOrderedSet`  If ordering is not important then `NSMutableSet` is your best bet

---

You should also be using `arc4random_uniform` instead of `arc4random %` to reduce modulo bias

Answer (score 2):

The most common approach is simply to fill the array with all possible values and then shuffle the array. See [What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
BOOl isFound = [_randomQuestionNumberArray containsObject:object];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int lowerBound = 0;
int long upperBound = numberOfQuestions;
int randomQuestionNumber = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);
NSDecimalNumber *currentNumber = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:randomQuestionNumber];
if (![_randomQuestionNumberArray containsObject:num]) {
    [_randomQuestionNumberArray addObject:num];
}
```