# Objective-C Shuffling Sound Files in an Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, audio, shuffle

I am trying to create a random sound generator with no repeated sounds.  I would like to use the fisher-yates algorithm.  Can anyone please explain how I should go about making an nsmutable array of sound files that would apply to the shuffling algorithm found here: [What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray)

Comment: Make an array of file names.

Comment: In this format?    NSMutableArray *sounds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"sound1", @"sound2", nil];   And where exactly do I put this array?

Comment: The format is up to you. BTW, `arrayWithObjects` can be replaced with `@[@"sound1", @"sound2"]` syntax.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that doesn't create a mutable array.

Comment: @user3477950 Ah, you're right. `[@[@"sound1", @"sound2"] mutableCopy]` then? :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, supposedly. (Apple could have added some syntax for mutable literals, couldn't they?)

Comment: Would this format be equally as successful or even better?: NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SoundFileName" ofType:@"wav"]; AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path],&mySoundID);   And I am still confused on how to get the array of these file names to follow the rules of that shuffle algorithm.