# Randomizing the contents of a plist

Tags: ios, random, plist

I'm new to Sprite Kit and I have 5 levels in my game. I want to randomize my levels in my game to be at any level once the game starts.

I created my levels in plists and I wanted to know if randomizing my plists would do the trick.

How would I get about randomizing my plists?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your plist is an array of dictionaries:

```
NSString *pathToPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"levels" 
                                                        ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *levels = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathToPlist];
NSDictionary *level = levels[arc4random_uniform(levels.count)];
GameScene *scene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.view.bounds.size 
                                         levelData:level];
```

Comment: I entered the GameScene line of code but I'm getting the following error: "Property 'size' not found on object of type 'SKView * `MyScene *scene = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:self.view.size 
                                         levelData:level];`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how large your plist is or how you load it in but I am assuming that it is loaded in as an NSArray of NSDictionaries.  You can turn the array into an NSMutableArray and then run some sort of randomization algorithm on it. [Here is an example of such an algorithm.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56656/1684508)

You can then load the levels from the array as you normally would.  If you post the format of the plist and how you parse it, I can further help you in coming up with a solution.