# Play Songs random out of my Mutable Array once

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm building an SongApp with random Sounds playing out of my Playlist.

I have now an **NSMutableArray** which contains Songs. For Example:

```
NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray     
   arrayWithObjects:
               @"Song1.mp3",
               @"Song2.mp3",
               @"Song3.mp3",
               @"Song4.mp3",
               @"Song5.mp3",
               @"Song6.mp3",
               @"Song7.mp3",
               @"Song8.mp3",
               @"Song9.mp3",
               nil];

      int i=0;
  for(i=0;i<=[array count]; i++)
 {

NSInteger rand=(arc4random() %9);
[array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i    
withObjectAtIndex:rand];
}
```

I declared it as Instance Method.

Now i have many Buttons in different Colors. And each Button should play a Song. But everytime i call the new View, the Button should play an other Song.

I hope you understand me :)

My problem is:

1. Is there any way, that when i want, that the yellow button for example plays "Song1" overtime in this View, but when i load the View another time it plays "Song5" for example?
2. How can i say each Button to play out of my Array? 
   I only know the

   ```
   NSString *play = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
   pathForResource:@"Song1" ofType:@"mp3"];
   NSURL *playURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pewPewPath];
   AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)playURL, & self.song1);
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.song1);
   ```

Hope you understand my questions :)

Thanks & best regards!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MPMediaPickerController class and implement it's methods to get songs from one's iPod Library.

If you have already have the files embedded in your application, simply pass the object at index to the Audio Services, while generating a random index each time.

Answer (score 1):

if you used `arc4random()`. then it will pickup random index from your array. that you are not predict. if you want the random function will work according to your requirement the you need to do manual coding for same according to your requirement.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use this code to generate random number in the range of your array:

```
int max =5;
int min =1;

int randNum = rand() % (max - min) + min;
```

Then you can use `[array objectAtIndex:randNum]` to access the song.

In your example:

```
NSString *play = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[array objectAtIndex:randNum] ofType:@"mp3"];
```

Comment: can you explain me why max 5 min 1?

Comment: do you mean this code                        int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<=[array count]; i++)
    {
        
        NSInteger rand=(arc4random() %3);
        [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i
                   withObjectAtIndex:rand];
    }

Comment: Hi. The max and min was an example. Min should be 0 and Max the number of your [array count]. See the updated answer

Answer (score -1):

At first add to your project category for NSMutableArray(shuffle).
There are many different variants in internet. For Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56656/1401067
http://nazcalabs.com/blog/how-to-shuffle-a-nsmutablearray-objective-c/

Then add this code in your controller. Or to another initialization place.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.sondsArray shuffle];
}
```

After that set different tags to all buttons. From 100(For example) to (100-1+self.sondsArray).

And the last step is buttons pressed action handling. So:

```
- (IBAction)songButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
      [self playSongWithName:sondsArray[button.tag-100]];
}
```

So. Good luck in you code =)

Comment: Hey, I down voted because I think suggesting to just download an NSMutableArray category isn't a great way to help someone learn. There's better ways that either don't involve categories on existing collections, or maybe help the person write there own.

Comment: I see you are very friendly guy. So... I wish you good luck in you learning. And please, Don't be so lasy!)

Comment: i can't follow you zevsVU... i should i tag the buttons?

Comment: When you create buttons in cycle you can write
for(int i=0; i<buttonsCount; i++) {
    UIButton *Button = ...
    //CreateButton and set rect
    button.tag = i;
}

Or make IBOutlets
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIButton *redButton;

self.redButton.tag = 100 + 0;
self.greenButton.tag = 100 + 0;
self.yellowButton.tag = 100 + 0;