# Change Images in UICollectionView after particular interval

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I have 6 cells in a `UICollectionView`.I would like to change the images in each `UICollectionViewCell` after a particular interval.How is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to change the image on each cell at once..or one at a time?

Comment: I want to change the image on each cel at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f  
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(updateImage:) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];

- (void)updateImage
{
     [yourImageview setImage:[UIImage imageWithName:@"image1"]];
     [yourCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Can I do something using tag?

Comment: *yes you can but collectionview reload  is best way *                                                         Here is an example to find image view with tag                                                        for (UIImageView *imgView in collectionView.subviews) {
    
    if ([imgView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        if(imgView.tag == 1//any tag which you want)
        [imgView    setImage:[UIImage imageWithName:@"image1"]];
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Reload the `UICollectionView`. It will call delegate methods of `CollectionView` & write your logic over there.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Write this to viewDidLoad

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(AutomaticScroll) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

//Add this method to the class 

-(void)AutomaticScroll
{
    if (i<[imgArray count])
    {
        NSIndexPath *IndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:IndexPath
                                         atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
        i++;
        if (i==[imgArray count])
        {
            i=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**3 Steps:**

1. Set a Timer
2. Shuffle Array
3. Refresh Collection View

**Step 1 : Set a Timer**

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f  
                             target:self 
                           selector:@selector(shuffleView:) 
                           userInfo:nil 
                            repeats:YES];
```

**Step 2: Shuffle Array**

Here I found a nice solution on how to shuffle the array using Category:

[What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray)

**Step 3: Reload Collection View**

```
- (void)shuffleView
{
     [MyArray shuffle];
     [yourCollectionView reloadData];
}
```